# IDE1007: The name 'options' does not exist in the current context (C#), despite (according to my knowledge) being in the same scope

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, syntax-error

### Problem

This part of my program causes the error: **`The name 'options' does not exist in the current context`**

```
public class CCL
    {
        public IWebDriver myDriver;
        public ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
         
    ^
    |

ignore lack of closing curly brace, the program continues after this
```

### Question

Why does this occur and how can I fix it? To my knowledge, I declared and assigned a value to `options` in the same scope that I attempted to add an argument to `options`. (Also, I included both `using OpenQA.Selenium` and `using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome`, if you're wondering.)

Comment: Your `options.AddArgument` call is fundamentally in the wrong place - it's a statement, which means it can't be directly contained in a class declaration. It needs to be in a method or constructor etc. (It's not quite the error message I'd expect, but you'll need to address it at some point...)

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'll try to put it in a place where it may work. Maybe post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I think I'd rather find a duplicate... this comes up quite a bit.

Comment: As I expected, I don't get that kind of error at all, which suggests there may be something else going on...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to run this code directly in the class with a [test]. These settings must be specified in the class where the driver is originally initialized. I can give you an example of what it looks like in my solution

I have class and method in which I initialize the browser and its driver:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
public void Init_Browser()
    {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        string chromeDriverPath = "/usr/local/bin/";
        IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath, chromeOptions);
    }
```

There I can also add chromeOptions and edit them just like you mentioned. Than I call it from test class

```
readonly StartBrowser brow2 = new StartBrowser();
IWebDriver driver;

[SetUp]
public void start_Browser()
{
    brow2.Init_Browser();
}

[Test]
public void TrafficErrors()
{
    driver = brow2.getDriver;
//...
```

Regards

Comment: @KirilKonovlov Please look at answer\comment by JonSkeet. That is the correct explanation. Even in your example that is the reason you are getting the error. Perhaps you want to change (or maybe even delete) the answer or provide a concrete example of what your explanation is. Also, please put the code in text form.

Comment: Thanks @vish for your review, sorry for uncomplete and unformatted answer by me. Does it look better now? I would like to help other people with the same problem too